# How to do conditional update in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am trying to update document's sub document like below lines of code

```
$bulkbatch = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(['ordered' => true]);  

$subDocumentStatus = array(
     "Status" => array(
          "CurrentStatus" => $this->EmployeeStatus,
          "StatusDate" => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($this->EmployeeStatusDate)*1000),
          "IsActive" => $IsActive 
      )
);

$bulkbatch->update( 
    array(
         '_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)
    ),
    array(
         '$addToSet' => $subDocumentStatus
    ), 
    [
         'multi' => true,  
         'upsert' => false
    ]
);

$this->manager->executeBulkWrite($this->collection, $bulkbatch);
```

I have document like

```
{
       "EmployeeNumber": "123456",
       "Instructor": NumberInt(1),
       "Department": ObjectId("5a8173e6d2ccda13240015a4"),
       "FirstName": "Faiza",
       "MiddleName": "Yousuf",

       "Status": [
                 {
                 "CurrentStatus": "Joined",
                 "StatusDate": ISODate("2018-02-28T23:00:00.0Z"),
                 "IsActive": NumberInt(1)
                 }
              ],
       ...
       ...
}
```

If  $this->EmployeeStatus contains "Joined" and  $this->EmployeeStatusDate contains some different values like for above document it contains "2019-05-28T23:00:00.0Z" (other than previous value) then it should be updated.

The above code is inserting another sub document 
with values like

```
  "Status": [
      {
        "CurrentStatus": "Joined",
        "StatusDate": ISODate("2018-02-28T23:00:00.0Z"),
        "IsActive": NumberInt(1) 
      },
      {
       "CurrentStatus": "Joined",
       "StatusDate": ISODate("2019-05-28T23:00:00.0Z"),
       "IsActive": NumberInt(1) 
      } 
    ],
     ...
```

I want that in the case of Joined the existing sub document should be updated.

Please help!!!

Comment: why do you use `executeBulkWrite`?

Comment: I was just trying to update this way as the other ways were not working in 3.6 version. If there is some other method... please tell us....

Comment: do you need in a single method call?

Comment: I am very new to mongo db. i dont know what to reply. I think yes i need single method call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution with two Mongo calls; first tries to update an existing sub-document; if no sub-document is modified then one is inserted in the main document.

Here is a unit-test that proves the solution works (the main function is `updateOrInsert`):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/MongoTestHelper.php';

use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID;
use MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime;
use tests\Dudulina\MongoTestHelper;

class TmpTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /** @var \MongoDB\Collection */
    private $collection;

    /** @var ObjectID */
    private $_id;

    public function test_subdocumentExists()
    {
        $statusDate = new UTCDateTime(strtotime("2018-02-28T23:00:00.0Z"));
        $employeeStatus = "Joined";

        /**
         * Test data
         */
        $this->collection->insertOne([
            "_id"            => $this->_id,
            "EmployeeNumber" => "123456",
            "Instructor"     => 1,
            "Department"     => new ObjectID("5a8173e6d2ccda13240015a4"),
            "FirstName"      => "Faiza",
            "MiddleName"     => "Yousuf",

            "Status" => [
                [
                    "CurrentStatus" => $employeeStatus,
                    "StatusDate"    => $statusDate,
                    "IsActive"      => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        /**
         * the real test
         */
        $this->updateOrInsert($employeeStatus, $statusDate, 0);


        /**
         * we verify the execution
         */
        $document = $this->collection->findOne([
            "_id" => $this->_id,
        ]);

        $this->assertCount(1, $document['Status']);
        $this->assertSame(0, $document['Status'][0]['IsActive']);

    }

    public function test_subdocumentDoesNotExists()
    {
        $statusDate = new UTCDateTime(strtotime("2018-02-28T23:00:00.0Z"));
        $employeeStatus = "Joined";

        /**
         * we insert some test data
         */
        $this->collection->insertOne([
            "_id"            => $this->_id,
            "EmployeeNumber" => "123456",
            "Instructor"     => 1,
            "Department"     => new ObjectID("5a8173e6d2ccda13240015a4"),
            "FirstName"      => "Faiza",
            "MiddleName"     => "Yousuf",

            "Status" => [
                [
                    "CurrentStatus" => 'SomeOtherStatus',
                    "StatusDate"    => new UTCDateTime(strtotime("2010-02-28T23:00:00.0Z")),
                    "IsActive"      => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        /**
         * the real test
         */
        $this->updateOrInsert($employeeStatus, $statusDate, 0);

        /**
         * we verify the execution
         */
        $document = $this->collection->findOne([
            "_id" => $this->_id,
        ]);

        /**
         * now there are 2 subdocuments inserted
         */
        $this->assertCount(2, $document['Status']);

        /**
         * we verify the second document
         */
        $secondSubDocument = $document['Status'][1];

        $this->assertSame(0, $secondSubDocument['IsActive']);
        $this->assertSame('Joined', $secondSubDocument['CurrentStatus']);
        $this->assertTrue($statusDate->toDateTime()->getTimestamp() === $secondSubDocument['StatusDate']->toDateTime()->getTimestamp());

    }

    /**
     * The function that you should do
     */
    private function updateOrInsert($employeeStatus, $statusDate, $isActive)
    {
        $updateResult = $this->collection->updateOne([
            "_id"                  => $this->_id,
            "Status.CurrentStatus" => $employeeStatus,
            "StatusDate"           => ['$ne' => $statusDate],
        ], [
            '$set' => [
                'Status.$.StatusDate' => $statusDate,
                'Status.$.IsActive'   => $isActive,
            ],
        ], [
            'upsert' => false,
        ]);

        if ($updateResult->getModifiedCount() === 0) {
            $this->collection->updateOne([
                "_id" => $this->_id,
            ], [
                '$addToSet' => [
                    'Status' => [
                        "CurrentStatus" => $employeeStatus,
                        "StatusDate"    => $statusDate,
                        "IsActive"      => $isActive,
                    ],
                ],
            ], [
                'upsert' => false,
            ]);
        }
    }

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->collection = (new MongoTestHelper())->selectCollection('eventStore');
        $this->collection->deleteMany([]);
        $this->_id = new ObjectID('47ecbc36e8fb4b50662adcf9');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait. Are these two operations (update then insert) done atomically? If not, someone can make an operation on the document (create it or modify) between these two operations. Making the insert when it really shoudn't?